# Experiece Builder Page Variance Governor Limit

Tags: community

Is there any governor limit on Page Variance and Number of Audience in Experience Builder? I could not find any documentation.

**Use Case/Background:**

We have around 5000 Accounts and have several (100 to 10000 contacts) under an account. In the community, we want to create different branding for accounts. At this moment, we are working with 10/15 Accounts as an Audience Group. We may have page variances for the audience groups.

Comment: Based on https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_audience_use_considerations.htm&type=0 ,  You can have up to 1,500 audiences per community.

Comment: In regards to page variations, I couldn't find any documentation. However, I am interested to know more about the use case you are exploring and the planned page number?

Comment: @Swetha added the use case/background

Answer (score 1):

For audiences limit, You can have up to 1500 audiences, as per the official salesforce document. For more detailed answer please refer the official document for "[Considerations for Using Audiences](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_audience_use_considerations.htm&type=0)" page.

Answer (score 0):

**Audience Limit:** Per the salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_audience_use_considerations.htm&type=0),

> You can have up to 1,500 audiences per community

**Page variations per community:**
As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_audience.htm),

> You can have up to 2,500 ExperienceVariation targets and 25,000 record targets.

It is also worth considering that having more than a handful of page variations per page would be of high maintenance. You would need to publish the whole site each time there is a change to even 1 variation.